# Providing dropdown items via an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

```
Rails 6
Bootstrap 4.4.1
```

I am using a dropdown in my application, but would like to provide the dropdown items via an array, instead of listing each items individually. This is what I'm using now:

```
.dropdown
  button.btn.btn-outline-secondary.dropdown-toggle aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"
    | Active
  .dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
    a.dropdown-item href="#"  Active
    a.dropdown-item href="#"  Inactive
```

The array would be:

```
items_list = ['Active', 'Inactive']
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to `select` or `select_tag` in the documentation. Here are the links: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag and https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

Basically you would use one over the other if your attribute in question is bound to an model object.

Comment: This is for a button, inside a table, so it would not work, but it gives me an idea on perhaps incorporation the table, inside a form

Comment: To make my comment clear, I am looking to use a form, but instead to have the dropdown selection, trigger an Ajax call to the Controller, which will do the right thing, and reload the partial